# How to set up usb-to-serial port on QNX?

Tags: serial-port

How to set up usb-to-serial device in QNX operating system to use it in code like `open("/dev/serusb1")`? I'm using VMWare to host QNX. How to check if USB adapter is properly connected?

Answer (score 2):

The driver you need to run is called devc-serusb, once executed, if the hardware is present you should see the /dev/serusbx device in /dev. (where x is your device index)

After connecting the usb-to-serial device to your physical box make sure it's then connected to your running QNX Vmware image and the device does indeed show up in /dev after running the driver.

Next step is to confirm it's working from the command line. Connect the other end of the serusb device to something that sends data. Then run this at the command line:

```
# cat /dev/serusb1
```

If you don't see any data coming in there might be a baud rate or other serial parameter that's off, take a look at the stty command documentation to set the parameters correctly. If you're running at 115200 8-n-1 then you can do something like this:

```
# stty baud=115200 < /dev/serusb1
```

If you can get data to display when you 'cat' the device from the command line then you're ready to open the device from within a program and read from it as though it was a file, something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int fd=-1;
    char ch;
    fd = open("/dev/serusb1", O_RDONLY);
    while(read(fd, ch, 1) > 0) {
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks! In my case I'm seeing `/dev/serN` instead.